# Align a table to bottom of page using Itext

Tags: itext, velocity

I have a velocity template which has a nested table. I want to align the content of last cell
which has a table inside it to the bottom of the page. I am writing the xml in velocity template and processing the pdf using IText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood your question, but there is the method **setExtendLastRow** on PdfPTable object that make the last row on the table high as long as needed to fill the current page, until bottom margin. Example:

```
  PdfPTable tabella = new PdfPTable(4);
  PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("some text here"));
  tabella.addCell(cell);
  tabella.addCell(cell);
  tabella.addCell(cell);
  tabella.addCell(cell);
  tabella.setExtendLastRow(true);
```

the table has only 4 cells that extends to the bottom of the page.